# How to develop a vscode extension that support assembly level debugging with source?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I've developed a debugger extension in vscode for some compiled language. Now I'm trying to add a new feature that could let the user dive into the assembly code during debugging. For example, one can debug step by step in the source code, meanwhile he could also chose to run instruction by instruction in the assembly codes. How can I implement something like that? Any extension examples that could do the similar things？